# How do I prevent clicking elements in a ListView row when in MutliChoiceMode in Android

Tags: android, listview, multichoiceitems

I have a Listview set up with a custom adapter. Each of the ListView's rows has a button and a seekbar that the user can interact with. I have also implemented a [MultiChoiceModeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener.html) to handle long clicking a ListView row in order to allow the user to delete multiple rows.

What I need is to prevent the user from interacting with each of the ListView's row elements (buttons, seekbars etc) when the ListView is in MultiSelect mode, by disabling them, and then to enable them once the user exits the multiselect mode.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried adding:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        View v = promptListView.getChildAt(i);
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

to the `onCreateActionMode()` method, but with no success, I'm still able to interact with the row elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the property `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the layout root of your list row. This will prevent the children from gaining focus, and will enable the user to click on the list row or any of its child views independently. Now you can disable (gray out) and re-enable any of the child views by using `setEnabled()` like you do in your code. Or if you would just like to prevent the user from being able to interact with a view without graying it out, you can use `setClickable()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you want the list item elements to interact to touch inside your custom adapter, so you can either set listeners there or disable them.

Comment: Doing it from within the adapter would involve setting a callback method and checking for conditions etc. which is a bit more complicated. I'd rather just simply iterate over the list and disable all the views but I don't quite know how to do that.